# how to display first page in localhost?

Tags: html, xampp, htdocs

I am using Xamp  to create a website, I am having a folder named HTML which has a page called `Cart.html`, the folder HTML is found in `htdocs` and I want `Cart.html` to appear as soon as localhost is being input in the browser. That is when I input `http:// localhost/`, the Cart.html page should appear. I am unable to do, can u suggest me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple HTACCESS rule:

```
Redirect 301 index.html Cart.html
```

Assuming they are in the same folder, otherwise replace with whatever needed

Answer (score 0):

Rename the cart.html to index.html & put it in htdocs as  'htdocs/index.html'

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .htaccess file with the following contents. The only problem here is that any sub folder will look for "Cart.html" as its default page

```
DirectoryIndex Cart.html
```

If you do not need the index.html file at all, I recommend deleting it and putting this DirectoryIndex instead

```
DirectoryIndex index.html Cart.html
```

This will cause all folders to look for "index.html" first and if it doesn't exist it will use "Cart.html"